# Mobile phone intergration from html 5

Tags: html, mobile, sensors

I am looking for a good resource that will tell me what html5 can access on mobile phones.

- can you have access over the accelerometer?
- can you use the compass?
- can you use the camera?

Any help or suggestions?

Comment: What do u mean ? html 5 is webcode and dont give you any access to your phone ?

Comment: ah right ok so if i make an app dependent just on the web i dont have any access over any off a mobile phone features?

Comment: BUT, if you wanna use HTML5 for an app, you can make a web-based app, but it still dosent give you any access to your phone.. OR you can try look at "Appcelerator" a program, for pc and mac where you can make apps in JS, PHP and more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes You can use HTML5 to use the functionalities of the mobiles camera, accelerometer,compass and many more 
Just follow the links below and woah!!! you will get exactly what you want.

[image]

http://docs.phonegap.com/

http://www.phonegap.com/home/

http://jquerymobile.com/

Comment: I think you accepted a wrong answer

Answer (score 1):

not at all.. HTML5 is executed by your browser, dosent give any access to your phone

Comment: what about this http://www.phonegap.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have access to Mobile components using interfaces.Such type of famous interface is Cordova(Phonegap).
It gives full access to it.
Check this [here](http://geeksarena.in/native-apps-vs-web-apps/)